# how to pass parameters to a script inside one other script

Tags: shell

i have one script `cc_update` which i want to call inside another script.
the `cc_update` script asks for 3 parameters in intearctive mode
the parameters it needs are `yes` `new` `this is a comment`

i need to call the `cc_update` script inside my script `label.sh`

how can i call the script inside my script so that the script proceeds furether.

```
echo "'yes' 'new' 'this is a comment'" | cc_update -m LATEST -f
```

i tried this line but it did not seem to work.
please suggest any workaround

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help you;

```
echo -e "yes\nnew\nthis is a comment\n" |
```

or

```
cc_update -m LATEST -f <<< $'"yes\nnew\nthis is a comment\n"'
```